# Find iOS UIView by tag dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, tags

I'm developing an app for iPhone and I have a strange problem. I tried to solve this by myself but after 3 days I didn't found a solution anyway.

I have a scrollview in which I dynamically create other views and subviews, this is the code:

```
for (int i=0; i<dim; i++) {

    UITextView *posted_nick= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(paddWidth, heightUpdateImageScrollview+paddHeight/2, screenWidth-2*paddWidth, 37)];
    //textview customization...
    [imagesScrollView addSubview:posted_nick];

    row_images_like = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(paddWidth,heightUpdateImageScrollview+paddHeight+37+heightImageInScrollView,screenWidth-2*paddWidth,80)];
    //set the tag = id
    row_images_like.tag = [id_image intValue];

        UIImageView *like_mini = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,15,25,25)];
        //imageview customization...
        //tag = id+1..
        NSInteger x = [id_image intValue] + 1;
        number_like.tag = x;
        [row_images_like addSubview:like_mini];

        UITextView *number_like = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(paddWidth*5/2,10,55,37)];
        //textview customization...
        //tag = id+2..
        NSInteger x = [id_image intValue] + 2;
        number_like.tag = x;
        [row_images_like addSubview:number_like];

    [imagesScrollView addSubview:row_images_like];
}
```

Now, all works great and when I click on the image view "like_mini", I can find the other views in the same row with the appropriate tag

```
(UIView *thisView = (UIView*)[imagesScrollView viewWithTag:ID_IMAGE];)
```

The problem is where I update my scrollview. When the user scrolls to the top, if there are new images to show, I call the same function that creates the views, and all the other views (that already exist) are moved some down. Why, when I try to find a view by tag in my scrollview, all works at the first time, but don't work for the new images created with the same code?

If i remove all the views in the scrollview, before adding the new views, it works. But i don't want to remove the oldest view.

When it works, I have in my console the view (row_images_like) with tag.
When it doesn't work, I receive a _UITextContainerView. What is this?

Hope I explained myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there the only reason the images moves down is because you are not assigning the proper **tags**, please give appropriate value of tag to uiview, uiimageview and uitextview.

```
row_images_like.tag = [id_image intValue] + 1000;
```

For fetching the view get it done similarly what you did before only add thousand to it.

```
UIView *thisView = (UIView*)[imagesScrollView viewWithTag:ID_IMAGE+1000];
```

Also one error :

```
number_like.tag = x;
```

How does the above line object i.e  "Number_like" comes before initialising it and change the tag value of other objects to "+2000" and "+3000"

Comment: Mate its too hard to sort this thing without rectifying the code and error.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all views added to scrollview, before loading scrollview again 
Write this line above for loop

```
 for (UIView *v in [imagesScrollView subviews])
{
    [v removeFromSuperview];
    v = nil;
}
```